# Exception appeared on code that previously was ok

Tags: c#, adodb

My project has suddenly default a problem in a function which has been working fine up until now. This is a function which calls a **stored procedure** on my sql server:

```
ADODB.Command MyCommand = new ADODB.Command();
ADODB.Parameter TableNameParameter = MyCommand.CreateParameter("@TableName", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 50, TableName);
MyCommand.Parameters.Append(TableNameParameter);
```

It throws an exception on the line above when it tries to append the first parameter:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type
>   'ADODB.InternalParameter'. Instances of types that represent COM
>   components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM
>   components;
>
> However they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM
>   component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

I found a similar post from someone who fixed this by changing a reference from 2.8 to 2.7 However i'm new to C# and dont know how to do this. Can someone help please, or suggest another fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fix is really just to roll back the reference file to a previous version you can do this in you solution by clicking on references in the solution explorer.

[image]

From there you select the reference for ADODB and right click and remove the 2.8 version.

Then you right click on references and select Add a reference.

Then you can browse for the file or select it in the COM list on that window.
Make sure you select the 2.7 version this time.

Comment: Yes that fixed it! I haven't changed any references previously. So I don't understand why this suddenly became an issue. Thanks for your help.